I would like to create a color scale the matches an image
I have the following color scale in an image and I would like to create something similar in a clut file.
Here is the scale BlueGreenRedYellow color scale
And here is an example of a clut file
[FLT]
min=0
max=0
[INT]
numnodes=5
[BYT]
nodeintensity0=1
nodeintensity1=64
nodeintensity2=128
nodeintensity3=191
nodeintensity4=255
[RGBA255]
nodergba0=0|0|0|0
nodergba1=0|96|100|64
nodergba2=112|102|0|128
nodergba3=223|106|0|191
nodergba4=255|253|0|255

Do you know how I could do that?
It would be great if you have any ideas on how to try to replicate this. I do not know how to approach this issue.

There are obviously two steps here: extracting the color scale from the image, and writing it out to your chosen file format. Thus, there are two questions, not one. Please ask only one question per post. The first task has already been asked many times, a Google search should point you to those previous questions.

@CrisLuengo This case is a bit simpler because there is only one color per column in the sample image.
Kostas, your image doesn't seem to have an alpha channel. How did you want to handle that?

@beaker I would not need an alpha for my use scenario

@Kostas I'm not familiar with CLUT file formats, but from my cursory search, it's either RGBA8888 or RGB565. So you either need an alpha channel, or you need to reduce the color space. Can you update your question with the format you want to use for your example? Getting the lookup table data is simple in MATLAB for the case you've presented, lut = squeeze(img(1,:,:)). Now it's just a question of writing the formatted data.
